# Can we use Handler for image in Sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need to display an image and action listener for the image.
Is it possible, if so please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is the [Ext.Img](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Img) component which allows you to do just this. It also has `tap` and `load` events so you know when a user taps on the image and when it loads.

Sample code:

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {
        var image = Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'image',
            src: 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png',
            listeners: {
                tap: function() {
                    console.log('Image tapped!');
                },
                load: function() {
                    console.log('Image loaded!');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add handler for image

```
  {
        xtype: 'button',
        icon: '/public/image.png',
    iconMask: false,
        handler: imageHandler

    }
```

and your handler function

```
var imageHandler = function(button, event) {
 // your handler function

 };
```